# Plutus Pioneer Week02: otherScript validator

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

In `gift.hs`, I do not understand the logic for why in the *lookups* for the `grab` contract there is `Constraints.otherScript validator`. The grabber is the consumer of the UTXO and thus the burden of providing the validator is on him, not the provider. It seems that the *other* is the provider who by definition does **not** have a validator.

```
grab :: forall w s e. AsContractError e => Contract w s e ()
grab = do
   utxos <- utxoAt scrAddress
   let orefs   = fst <$> Map.toList utxos
      lookups  = Constraints.unspentOutputs utxos      <>
                 Constraints.otherScript validator -- ###### THIS LINE #####
      tx :: TxConstraints Void Void
      tx       = mconcat [mustSpendScriptOutput oref $ Redeemer $ I 17 | oref <- orefs]
   ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraintsWith @Void lookups tx
   void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ txId ledgerTx
   logInfo @String $ "collected gifts"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The grabber is the consumer of the UTXO and thus the burden of providing the validator is on him, not the provider.

Correct! And I feel like this might be where your misunderstanding is.

You are right that "the burden of providing the validator" is on the grabber. The `grab` and `give` functions are called *offchain* to construct txs to perform those actions. So the line in question is in fact the code where the grabber "provid[es] the validator."

The `Constraits` are a way to *declaratively* specify

1. What kind of script and UTxOs you want to target with your tx (lookups)
2. What kind of tx you want to send (tx)

When we include

```
Constraints.otherScript validator
```

we are just saying that we want to target our `validator` with your `tx`. Or, it might be more accurate to say, we will need our `validator` in order to perform the `tx`.

---

Admittedly the name of the function as well as the documentation doesn't shed too much light on what it's doing:

```
-- | A script lookups value with a validator script
otherScript :: Validator -> ScriptLookups a
otherScript vl =
    let addr = Address.scriptAddress vl in
    mempty { slOtherScripts = Map.singleton addr vl }
```

Comment: So `otherScript` really means `ourScript`? This is very confusing.

Comment: That's not quite right. Maybe think of it as adding "another" script to the lookups. You could theoretically include multiple validators if you're spending outputs from different scripts in a single transaction. Remember, validators just check if you are allowed to spend outputs at a script address.

Comment: So it seems that in this particular case for grabbing, since there is only one grabber (at a time), there is just one validator. And hence there is no ambiguity in simply stating `otherScript` because there's just one script out there altogether for this particular transaction.